# pageref to label in last page in resume.cls

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using the class [resume.cls](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/resume-writing-example-latex-template-linux-curriculum-vitae-professional-cv-layout-format-text-p54/) for writing my curriculum.

I would like to use as page numbers the text "page k out of n", but I seem not to be able to get a reference to the last page.

- If I add a simple label 'lastone' at the end of the resume and use \pageref{lastone} the reference stays undefined no matter how many times I compile the source.
- If I use the package 'lastpage' I get an error related to a missing curly brace (which disappears as soon as I do not include that package).
- If I use the package 'zref-lastpage' and refer to the last one with \zpageref{LastPage}, I get an error related to an undefined macro.

Is there any way I can have a reference to the last page in order to insert its page number?

This is an example (you need to download the .cls file because I could not find a way to attach files).

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{resume}

\usepackage{zref-lastpage}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}%                                                                                                                        
{\normalsize\slshape CV di Tizio \hfil \upshape pag. {\thepage} di \zpageref{LastPage}} % \pageref{ultima}} % \zpageref{LastPage}}                              
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\@evenfoot} \makeatother

\begin{document}
\name{\Large Tizio -- \it Curriculum Vitae et Studiorum}

\begin{resume}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{\mysidestyle Informazioni\\ personali}\vspace{2mm}\label{informazioni-personali}
This is me

% ENDING                                                                                                                                                      
bye

\label{ultima}\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a MWE? Refer: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: You are right. I modified my initial post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\label` uses a deferred writing, when the page is shipped out. At this time the page number is known for sure. Because of the asynchronous output routine this is not guaranteed otherwise. However, deferred writing is void after the *last* page is shipped out, because there is no page for the writing to take place.

Therefore the packages uses `\immediate\write` for the last label, e.g. package `lastpage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\begin{document}
First page.
Last page is \pageref{LastPage}.
\newpage
Last page
\end{document}
```

The same example with package `zref-lastpage`. Note: `\zpageref` is provided by package `zref-user`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-lastpage,zref-user}
\begin{document}
First page.
Last page is \zpageref{LastPage}.
\newpage
Last page
\end{document}
```

The total number of pages can be different from the page number of the last page, because the numbering might change (title page, front matter, ...).
`zref` provides package `zref-totpages` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-totpages}
\begin{document}
First page.
Number of pages is \ztotpages.
\newpage
Last page
\end{document}
```

Also `\ztotpages` uses the reference system, because the number of pages is known *after* the last page.

### Class `resume`

The class [`resume`](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/files/p54-resume/resume.cls) from the question sabotages the reference system by using `\nofiles`. Then auxiliary files are not written, including references, thus labels remain unknown regardless of the number of LaTeX runs.

Workaround:

```
\let\nofiles\relax
\documentclass{resume} % http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/files/p54-resume/resume.cls
```

Comment: I have already tried using zref-totpages, but \ztotpages gives always zero. I think it's a problem related to the resume class. However, for my resume I have full control of the page numbering so something pointing at the last page or the one before would be ok.

Comment: @AntonioSesto: Two LaTeX runs are needed. The total number of pages is known *after* the last page, but `\ztotpages` is usually used before.

Comment: I know: I run latex (pdflatex) four or five times before posting the comment.

Comment: @AntonioSesto: See the updated answer, the class `resume` from the question calls `\nofiles` that disables auxiliary files.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That fixed the problem! It's the first time I see that configuration: what's the reason not to produce any aux file?